# When is the Parse server cloud code beforeSave called?

Tags: parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I created cloud code like this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
  console.log('before saving user')
  if (!request.object.get("email")) {
    response.error("email is required for signup");
  } else {
    response.success();
  }
});
```

But when I called Parse.User.save, this cloud code is never been called. Why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For users you have to use user.signUp()

> var user = new Parse.User();
>
> return user.signUp();

it returns a promise, and should hit your beforeSave function.